# Подключение в UICC с использование библиотеки Seek-for-android

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Занимаюсь разработкой приложения использующего UICC на которой присутствует Java Card Applet.  Для этого я использую библиотеку Seek-for-android.

Для теста использовал Пример приложения с сайта библиотеки https://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/wiki/UsingSmartCardAPI + Samsung Galaxy S III + работающую UICC карту.

Мой код:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            button = new Button(this);
            button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            button.setText("Click Me");
            button.setEnabled(false);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            try {
                                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Retrieve available readers...");
                                    Reader[] readers = seService.getReaders();
                                    if (readers.length < 1)
                                            return;

                                    byte aid[] = new byte[] {(byte)0xA0, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x20,0x10};
                                    SECardIdentifier id = new SECardIdentifier(aid);
                                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Create Session from the first reader...");
                                    Session session = readers[0].openSession();
                                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(session.getReader().getName())+"   "+id.getAid().toString());
                                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Create logical channel within the session...");
                                    Channel channel = session.openLogicalChannel(aid);

                                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Send HelloWorld APDU command");
                                    byte[] respApdu = channel.transmit(new byte[] {
                                                    (byte) 0x90, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 });

                                    channel.close();

                                    // Parse response APDU and show text but remove SW1 SW2 first
                                    byte[] helloStr = new byte[respApdu.length - 2];
                                    System.arraycopy(respApdu, 0, helloStr, 0, respApdu.length - 2);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, new String(helloStr), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error occured:", e);
                                    return;
                            }
                    }
            });

            layout.addView(button);
            setContentView(layout);

            try {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "creating SEService object");
                    seService = new SEService(this, this);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Binding not allowed, uses-permission org.simalliance.openmobileapi.SMARTCARD?");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
            if (seService != null && seService.isConnected()) {
                    seService.shutdown();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void serviceConnected(SEService service) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "seviceConnected()");
            button.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

}

В LogCat я вижу следующее:

```
    05-13 11:23:09.979: I/HelloSmartcard(17588): creating SEService object
05-13 11:23:09.984: V/SEService(17588): bindService successful
05-13 11:23:10.054: I/HelloSmartcard(17588): seviceConnected()
05-13 11:23:10.054: V/SEService(17588): Service onServiceConnected
05-13 11:23:11.444: I/HelloSmartcard(17588): Retrieve available readers...
05-13 11:23:11.444: I/HelloSmartcard(17588): Create Session from the first reader...
05-13 11:23:11.444: I/HelloSmartcard(17588): SIM: UICC   A0000000032010
05-13 11:23:11.444: I/HelloSmartcard(17588): Create logical channel within the session...
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588): Error occured:
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588): java.lang.SecurityException: Connection refused !!!
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at org.simalliance.openmobileapi.SEService.checkForException(SEService.java:553)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at org.simalliance.openmobileapi.SEService.openLogicalChannel(SEService.java:365)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at org.simalliance.openmobileapi.Session.openLogicalChannel(Session.java:131)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at com.example.com.pentegy.nfctest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-13 11:23:11.634: E/HelloSmartcard(17588):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Получаю я SecurityException: Connection Refused !!!

Возможно кто то имел дело с этой библиотекой, Какие есть способы решения данной проблемы?

Comment: `java.lang.SecurityException: Connection refused !!!` означает нарушение безопасности - скорее всего отсутствует какой-то пермишен на соединение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Я тоже так думал. Сравнил с аналогичным рабочим приложением. Все на месте.
У меня есть работающая программа. Она работает с той UICC что у меня есть. Поэтому я уверен что все, впринципе, рабочее. Вот теперь и не знаю куда копать.

Comment: Часто бывает, что API изменилось со времени написания примера - вкурите доки и посмотрите - наверняка добавился `SecurityException`